# Mail move error | Imaplib | COPY command error: BAD [b'Command Argument Error. 12']

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib

I wish to move emails to my custom folder named 'Test Folder' using imaplib library. I am able to move email to "Archive" folder but not in my custom made folder.

I get below error when attempted to copy an email to my 'Test Folder'.

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 3
      1 for num in msg_num[0].split():
      2     # imap.uid('COPY', num, 'archive')
----> 3     imap.copy(num, 'Test Folder')

File c:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py:486, in IMAP4.copy(self, message_set, new_mailbox)
    481 def copy(self, message_set, new_mailbox):
    482     """Copy 'message_set' messages onto end of 'new_mailbox'.
    483 
    484     (typ, [data]) = .copy(message_set, new_mailbox)
    485     """
--> 486     return self._simple_command('COPY', message_set, new_mailbox)

File c:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py:1230, in IMAP4._simple_command(self, name, *args)
   1228 def _simple_command(self, name, *args):
-> 1230     return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))

File c:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\imaplib.py:1055, in IMAP4._command_complete(self, name, tag)
   1053     self._check_bye()
   1054 if typ == 'BAD':
-> 1055     raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
   1056 return typ, data

error: COPY command error: BAD [b'Command Argument Error. 12']
```

Below is my code.

```
import imaplib

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com")
imap.login("Email", "Password")
imap.select("Inbox")

_, msg_num = imap.search(None, 'SINCE "25-Jan-2021" BEFORE "26-Jan-2021"')

for num in msg_num[0].split():
    imap.copy(num, 'Test Folder')
```

I tried below code for moving email to archive and it moved and gave no error.

```
imap.copy(num, 'archive')
```

What am I doing wrong? I did try make different folder names but encountered error in all the names.

Comment: If your folder has spaces, it must be wrapped in quotes: ‘“Test Folder”’

Comment: Yes, I was able to search that. Thanks.